# How can I store list items when there is no internet connection (data come from server)

Tags: java, android, json, listview, android-volley

Regarding
I have a listview contains 4 items 3 of them are texts and fourth is image 
all data are on server within json 
the code work correctly but when the internet is off all items and list does not appear how can make the list works with and without internet connection 
because I add everyday new items to database 
and this my code

```
    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                     try {
                        JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("allstudents");
                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject respons = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            String id = respons.getString("id");
                            String name = respons.getString("name");
                            String info = respons.getString("info");
                            String img = respons.getString("img");
                            link = respons.getString("link");
                            voicelink = respons.getString("voicelink");
                            listitmes.add(new listitme(id, name, info, img, link, voicelink));
                            allitems();
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
            , new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e("VOLLEY", "ERROR");
        }
    }

    );
    requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);

}


public void allitems() {
    listAdapter lsadapter = new listAdapter(listitmes);
    listView.setAdapter(lsadapter);

}
```

any solution please I searched a lot but no any answer 
and I did not find any thing like here on StackOverflow.Com

Answer (score 0):

Look at https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.

With Shared SharedPreferences you can save the list and call it if there is no wifi!

Comment: I know I cannot connect without internet bu I wanted how can store that even there is no connection

Comment: ohhhhhh. I see. Look at sharedPreferences. You can save the data offline and then call it back. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences

Answer (score 0):

what you can do is:

- Save the data that you download, to a file (**[image](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files#WriteInternalStorage)**)/properties (**[text](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage#pref)**) as soon as you receive data from Internet. ()
- **[Display](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView)** a message in your activity when the data was fetched (e.g. Last Synced : Timestamp).
- If you can can't connect to Internet to get the new data, load the data from file/properties.
- If you can't connect to Internet and don't have any saved data, display a message (e.g. can't connect to Internet - may be color it to highlight it's an error).

my 2 cents...

Comment: that are what I want actually but no tutorials did that unfortunately